# How can I lookup / retrieve the Rack::Timeout timeout value that has been configured in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rack

In our Rails application we are using rack-timeout 0.4.2 and have it configured in `config/initializers/timeout.rb` for prod and staging like so:

```
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
  Rack::Timeout.timeout = (ENV['RACKTIMEOUT'] || 25).to_i # seconds
end
```

When we upgrade the gem in the near future those values will probably be set as `service_timout` or `wait_timeout`.

I want to retrieve what this value is set to in the application to use as a default for any `MySidekiqWorker.perform_in(CURRENT_TIMEOUT_VALUE, ...)` call, instead of just writing `(ENV['RACKTIMEOUT'] || 25).to_i` everywhere it's needed. The problem I am trying to work around here is [this sidekiq issue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-find-modelname-with-id12345), where it can't find the Model yet because it hasn't been committed. It's not an option right now to refactor these calls into `after_commit` hooks.

this try gives the following:

```
0> Rack::Timeout.timeout
=> private method `timeout' called for Rack::Timeout:Class
```

and `Rails.app.configuration` only has
`Rails.app.configuration.middleware.includes? Rack::Timeout` as `true` and doesn't give any values that I can see.

Comment: My initial answer missed the 0.4.2 version requirement. I've updated it to reflect the version you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about https://github.com/sharpstone/rack-timeout.

0.4.2 allows reading the value using some [backwards-compatible methods](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack-timeout/0.4.2/Rack/Timeout/ClassLevelProperties/ClassMethods#service_timeout-instance_method):

```
Rack::Timeout.service_timeout
=> 25
```

It seems like the wrong way to approach the issue. You're setting the value in Rails based off an environment variable, so just make sure it's defined in `ENV`:

```
# config/initializers/timeout.rb
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
  ENV['RACKTIMEOUT'] ||= '25'
  Rack::Timeout.timeout = ENV['RACKTIMEOUT'].to_i
end
```

And then you can read it from anywhere:

```
MySidekiqWorker.perform_in(ENV['RACKTIMEOUT'].to_i, ...)
```

It's probably best to break out the logic for `ENV` into a separate configuration using something like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to make it all a little more manageable.

That'll make your life a bit easier if you ever decide to upgrade to newer versions of the gem. I'd recommend looking into it because 0.4.2 is about 4 years old now. 0.6.0 is the most recent version and the gem [configures itself using some default environment variables](https://github.com/sharpstone/rack-timeout#configuring) so all you have to do is set `ENV['RACK_TIMEOUT_SERVICE_TIMEOUT']` and then you can skip the initializer altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this is what I needed, it didn't occur to me to assign to the env var as I wanted to avoid touching the initialization if I could, but I will just do that. We will be upgrading to the latest rack-timeout sometime soon as well so with what you suggested I can continue to use an ENV var in the perform_in call.